# Is it against proper MVC style to send error messages from the model?

Tags: model-view-controller

Or should error messages be handled in the view? I usually try to just send true and false from my models.

Great to hear what you guys do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

agreed.  Model should be happy to throw up stuff as long as it is generated from information readily available to the model.

Comment: It's important to add though, that all the information that is needed to deal with the error should be passed with the error.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the model to throw an exception which can be handled by the view (and presented the the end user if appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

My models handle validation by throwing an exception when being persisted.  The validation logic will collect a set of validation errors, including messages.  If there are any validation errors, an exception is thrown.  Views/controllers can interrogate the model to find the appropriate error messages if desired.